# Why link error on struct itself?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I use Visual Studio 2013 express version. I had a declaration like that:

```
typedef struct tagActionData
{
    int             id;
    float           BoxW, BoxH;
    bool            bBoxRotate; // ==0 : 不BOX2D旋轉, ==1 會依 BOX2D 角度旋轉
    int             FreeCounter;
    char            SoundName[21];
    int             WindIndex;
    float           fWindRate;
    view_port       vp;
    // ... other fields ...

} ACTIONDATA, *LPACTIONDATA;
```

When I build my code, compilation is ok, but I got the link error:

```
2>LINK : warning LNK4098: 預設的程式庫 'MSVCRT' 與其他使用的程式庫衝突，請使用 /NODEFAULTLIB:library
2>cocos_igs_action.obj : error LNK2001: 無法解析的外部符號 "struct tagActionData * ActionData" (?ActionData@@3PAUtagActionData@@A)
```

That's really weird. Why struct declaration can cause link error?
Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you call a function that is not in your code.

Comment: It's not erroring on a struct declaration but on the declaration of a global pointer variable pointing to a struct.

Comment: And that's why you should use English interface language in all the software.

Comment: What if you write `typedef ACTIONDATA * LPACTIONDATA;` on a separate line?

Comment: I got your points. I do doubt the chinese in comment area raise this error, I would take it out for later.

Comment: @naive231 It isn't just the Chinese comments.  The error message itself has the important information in Chinese.

Comment: @naive231, it's Chinese in the error that makes it more difficult for the readers to figure out what's your problem is. However, it's pretty clear that the error is about something called `ActionData` (case matters!) and you haven't posted that.

Comment: @naive231, the comment probably didn't cause this error but there did and do exist tool-chains that don't support unicode encoded source files.

Comment: Ok,  guys. Thanks your responses! :)